# Better solution for using an Entity Manager in an ASP.NET request?

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, devforce

The current advice for using an Entity Manager in an ASP.NET request seems to be to just set the `AuthorizedThreadID` property to `NULL` (reference [1](http://drc.ideablade.com/devforce-2012/bin/view/Documentation/entitymanager-not-thread-safe) and [2](http://drc.ideablade.com/ApiDocumentation/IdeaBlade.EntityModel~IdeaBlade.EntityModel.EntityManager~AuthorizedThreadId.html)).  While that works, it seems like that is turning off a very important 'safety net'.  While I try very hard to use the Entity Manager in a thread-safe way, it is still nice to have that safety net in case I get it wrong...so I'd rather not have to just set it to `NULL`.

In the ASP.NET world, there is still roughly a single thread of execution - it's just that the actual thread can change when you are doing async work.  I can think of a few possible solutions:

1. The `EntityManager.SafeThreadingCheck()` method does some kind of extra magic to support ASP.NET requests.  I can understand that IdeaBlade might not want to do this...which leads me to the second option...
2. `EntityManager` provides some extensibility points for me to provide my own version of `SafeThreadingCheck()` where I can implement the special magic for verifying that the entity manager is still 'logically' on the request thread.  I might have to do some weird stuff here but I don't think it would be terribly complicated.
3. I try to use other extensibility points to detect when I should call my own `FancySafeThreadingCheck()` method.  This has the downside that I have to try to hook into all the necessary places whereas the existing `SafeThreadingCheck()` method is already being called (presumably) from all the necessary places at exactly the best time.

I can understand this might not be the highest priority feature request but it also seems like it might not be too hard (at least for option #2).  Or perhaps there are some other workarounds that may be better?  My end goal is to avoid turning off this safety check...I'm open to options to get there.

Comment: I've opined in the past that the AuthorizedThreadId logic was a naïve attempt at enforcing thread affinity.  The EntityManager does not truly have a need for thread affinity, but does require thread safe access.  We can look at option 2 - maybe making the method virtual.

Comment: Thanks. Any idea on when you might have an update on this?  Making the method virtual would probably be the easiest but wouldn't be ideal for us. We are often stuck with a 'standard' EntityManager...especially for server-side calls (like InvokeServerMethod calls) - in that case, the 'server entity manager' is just a vanilla EntityManager and not our custom class inheriting from EntityManager.  Instead, if there was an event we could subscribe to? Or maybe a way to pass a custom delegate to an existing Entity Manager?

Comment: The custom delegate approach would probably be best.  We can have this in the 7.2.4 release - and I don't have a date for this yet.

Comment: That is great news.  We can wait until 7.2.4.  For now, we'll just keep setting AuthorizedThreadID to null.  If you make these comments into an answer, I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DevForce 7.2.4 will include the feature to set a delegate on the EntityManager to provide custom authorized thread ID logic.